# using php oauth on server with strict connection settings

Tags: php, oauth, proxy

My server is blocking connections to the server that handles the authentication that I pass to oauth.  So I was wondering if there was a way to make the OAuth fetch method go through a proxy somehow?

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) is a standard, are you referring to a specific PHP implementation?

Comment: ahh yes, the one that is installed through pecl.  This one: http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php